# Cut and Paste Loop with VBA in Excel Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

For my current project, I'm trying to move a group of cells down in a worksheet up to a certain number of rows. i figured the easiest way to do this is to cut the 2nd to last group and paste it in place of the last group, then cut the 3rd to last group and paste it in the place where the 2nd to last was and so on (since I don't want to be the list to be ever expanding) using the following code:

```
For i = 298 To 8 Step -5
Sheets("Calc").Range(Cells(i, 130), Cells(i + 4, 130)).Cut
Sheets("Calc").Range(Cells(i + 5, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

However, I always get a runtime error 1004 on the second line of code.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: use `Sheets("Calc").Range(Cells(i, 130), Cells(i + 4, 130)).Cut Sheets("Calc").Cells(i + 5, 1)`. Btw, why not jsut select all groups but last, cut them and paste on please of second group?

Comment: @simoco I'm sorry if i'm missing something, but I don't quite get your code.. I get the error on the second line of code, which you idn't change at all.. The thing about the groups on the other hand - yes, you are right =)

Comment: ok, remove your two lines: 1) `Sheets("Calc").Range(Cells(i, 130), Cells(i + 4, 130)).Cut` and 2) `Sheets("Calc").Range(Cells(i + 5, 1)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
` and peplace them with single line: `Sheets("Calc").Range(Cells(i, 130), Cells(i + 4, 130)).Cut Destination:=Sheets("Calc").Cells(i + 5, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
With Sheets("Calc")
   For i = 298 To 8 Step -5
       .Range(.Cells(i, 130), .Cells(i + 4, 130)).Cut Destination:=.Cells(i + 5, 130)
   Next i
End With
```

Howerver, as I see, you can do it without loop:

```
With Sheets("Calc")
    .Range(.Cells(8, 130), .Cells(302, 130)).Cut Destination:=.Cells(13, 130)
End With
```

Btw, I've changed your destination range from `Sheets("Calc").Cells(i + 5, 1)` to `Sheets("Calc").Cells(i + 5, 130)` (as I understood your question, you want to move cells down, but not across)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked perfectly. I guess I didn't think of the second option because I am still relatively new to VBA, and some of the "working normally with excel" mindset is still sticking to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `PasteSpecial` with `Cut`

You can either copy and paste as values

OR

You can cut and paste